# How to convert NSArray of NSStrings into Json String iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa, nsarray

I have an Array of Roll Numbers

```
NSArray *rollArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"22", @"24", @"11", nil];
```

I need to send this array in a Web Service request

whose format is like this (in JSON format)

JSON data

```
{
  "existingRoll":["22","34","45","56"], // Array of roll numbers
  "deletedRoll":["20","34","44","56"] // Array of roll numbers
}
```

but I am facing problem in converting Array of Roll numbers (rollArray) into json String 
in the desired format.

I am trying this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [postDict setValue:[rollArray componentsJoinedByString:@","] forKey:@"existingRoll"];

 NSString *str = [Self convertToJSONString:postDict]; // converts to json string

 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:str options:0 error:nil];

 [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

I am using iOS 7

Comment: Can you add the code that causing the problem ? And what is the problem ?

Comment: NSDictionary is successfully converted to/from JSON format with NSJSONSerialization. Check my answer please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to use the following code snippets:

1. `[rollArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]`
2. `NSString *str = [Self convertToJSONString:postDict];`

You can create JSON by using the following code:

```
NSArray *rollArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"22", @"24", @"11", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[postDict setValue:rollArray forKey:@"existingRoll"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];

// Checking the format
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May be i am tired of working today I was just applying extra mind on such simple thing.

Comment: @DineshKaushik: Thanks for the comment. Time to drink some coffee :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
NSDictionary *object = @{
    @"existingRoll":@[@"22",@"34",@"45",@"56"],
    @"deletedRoll":@[@"20",@"34",@"44",@"56"]
};

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:object]) {
    NSData* data = [ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [postDict setValue:@"Login" forKey:@"methodName"];
    [postDict setValue:@"admin" forKey:@"username"];
    [postDict setValue:@"12345" forKey:@"password"];
    [postDict setValue:@"mobile" forKey:@"clientType"];


    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];

    // Checking the format
    NSString *urlString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
    NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jsonRequest=%@", urlString];

    //@"jsonRequest={\"methodName\":\"Login\",\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"12345\",\"clientType\":\"web\"}";

    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to get Json string from any type of NSArray :

```
NSArray *rollArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"22", @"24", @"11", nil];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:rollArray options:0 error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Json string is: %@", jsonString);
```